# Close button in a modal dialog

Tags: jquery

I used the following which works correctly but I need to have a close button rather than closing automatically how to do that?

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
     $('#app').click(function() { 
         $.blockUI({ 
             theme:     true, 
             title:    'Welcome to your page', 
             message:  '<p>Please have a look..</p>', 
             timeout:   2000 
        }); 
    });    
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
     $('#app').click(function() { 
         $.blockUI({ 
             theme:     true, 
             title:    'Welcome to your page', 
             message:  $('#message')
        }); 
    });

   $('.close').click(function() {
       $.unblockUI(); 
        return false; 
   });    
});
```

And put the below into the html content.

```
<div id="message" style="display:none;">
    <p>Please have a look..</p><button class="close">close</button>
</div>
```